# Better way to code this - Checking comment for banned word

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace, profanity

Is there a better, faster way of doing the below?

This is a method from a class to check if a comment has a banned word in it, if so the comment needs to be manually approved.

I don't really want to change the way my models/database works so `$this->get_words()` ideally needs to stay (which returns an array of objects with properties generated form DB fields).

P.S I know profanity filters, etc are frowned upon but in this scenario it will just make a comment need manual approval.

```
public function check_string($str) {
    // Put banned words in an array
    $banned_words = [];
    foreach ($this->get_words() as $word) {
        $banned_words[] = $word->word;
    }

    $patterns = array(
        '/[_.-]/', '/1/', '/3/', '/4/', '/5/', '/6/',
        '/7/',     '/8/', '/0/', '/z/', '/@/'
    );
    $replacements = array(
        '',  'i', 'e', 'a', 's', 'g',
        't', 'b', 'o', 's', 'a'
    );

    // Turn str into array of individual words
    $str_words = explode(" ", $str);

    foreach ($str_words as $str_word) {
        $str_word = strtolower(preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$str_word));
        if (in_array($str_word, $banned_words, true))
            return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You're aware there's really no way to effectively block _all_ possible profanity, right?

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, I'm aware. As I say, the profanity is not blocked or replaced - it just means the comment will need to be approved before appearing on the site. Believe it or not we have actually had legal issues regarding comments on our site - so making, at least most of, the comments containing profanity moderation based should help us.

Comment: Hm, I see. I'd suggest making the filter catch a lot, then. (digits that are directly followed by strings without white-space or vice-versa, strings containing non-ASCII characters, strings containing punctuation normally not used in strings: `\/|[]{}<>`, stuff like that.

Comment: Good Advice, I will add that in.

Answer (score 1):

you can place the **bad word** and the **replacement word** in a file.
like this -

```
badword1,replaceword1
badword2,replaceword2
badword3,replaceword3
```

read the file like this and create an array of **bad word** and the **replacement word**-

```
$allline_arr = file('bad_word.txt');
$badword_arr = array();
foreach ($allline_arr as $line) {
    $badword_arr[] = explode(',', $line);
}
```

-OR-

```
$file = fopen("bad_word.txt","r");
$badword_arr = array();
while(! feof($file))
{
  $line = fgets($file);
  $badword_arr[] = explode(',', $line);
}
fclose($file);
```

now you can use it as you wish...

Comment: Hi, I'm not actually replacing the bad words. Just checking to see if they exist. Would reading them from a file be faster then from a database?

Comment: if you store the texts in file instead of database, you can modify it in a simplest way.

Comment: you can create a csv file of those comma separated word and in php code read that file and generate a insert query if you want to store those words to database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
var bannedWords = ["NO", "NO NAME", "NONAME", "MISS", "MS", "MS.", "MR", "MR.", "MRS", "MRS."];

function checkBannedWords(value) {
            var rgx = new RegExp(bannedWords.join("|"), "gi");
            if (value.replace(rgx,'*').indexOf('*') != -1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```